# Will pop scope widget only works for the last screen of my project I want to work it on each page or specific pages

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have wrote code for splash screen and main screen my custom splash screen navigate to main screen after 3 seconds I have applied WillPopScope on both screen but it is only working on splash screen. when I disable splash and only run main screen than WillPopScope works well but when I applied splash screen than it did not work on main screen. I want to have such functionality on main screen and one webview screen how can I use this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'main.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
      MaterialApp(
    home: splash(),
  ));
}

class splash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _splashState createState() => new _splashState();
}

class _splashState extends State<splash> {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 3),
        () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
      return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Do you want to exit?"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, false);
                  },
                  child: Text("No")),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, true);
                  },
                  child: Text("yes"))
            ],
          ));
    }
    Orientatoin();
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            child: Image.asset('imges/splash.png'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,

      );
  }
}

void Orientatoin() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code edit `Navigator` code to replace the Splash page with `MyApp()`:

```
Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 3),
            () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
        ));
```

Add `WillPopScope` in your `MyApp()`

Comment: That pushReplacement perfectly works. you are awesome anmol stay blessed.

Comment: kindly explain  the difference between pushReplacement and push I will be very thankful.

Comment: `pushReplacement` -- Replace the current route of the navigator by pushing the given route and then disposing the previous route once the new route has finished animating in. whereas `push` -- simply Push the given route onto the navigator.
check - https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31